# Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode): 'GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h' file not found

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-maps-flutter

In my Flutter project I can no longer compile the app. Every time I try, in the iOS simulator, I get the error "Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode): 'GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h' file not found". So far I have been using google_maps_flutter version: ^2.5.3 without any problems. I don't know how to solve it.

I tried to clean the project, remove the hidden .pub-cache folder, reinstall the pods, but without success.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm running a flutter project with SDK version 3.13.7, the goole_maps_flutter version is 2.5.0, the Xcode version is the latest on the store. The app stopped building iOS after updating to the latest Mac version 14.3.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same error and had been trying to fix it for a couple of days already.

I tried these and **nothing** worked

```
rm -rf Pods Podfile.lock
pod cache clean --all  
flutter pub cache clean
```

What finally fixed it was deleting `ios` directory and putting if back using git.